# PHP self-form variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

I was wondering if it is possible to use a variable from a form as its own URL... *its hard to explain in my opinion,* heres an example:

**matchmaking.php:**

```
$search_summoner = $_POST['search_summoner'];
    echo '<form method="post" action="matchmaking.php?search=' . $search_summoner . '">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="search_summoner">';
    echo '<input type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

As you can see the action sends it back to matchmaking.php but with a variable from the form which was just submitted. The code above, which I have tried, didn't seem to work; So I wondered if anyone else had any ideas on how to do this...

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: **How** didn't it work? Did it explode?

Comment: I'm not clear on the purpose of this? If you have the value in `POST` already, it's likely been used from a form already.

Comment: What's the generated source?

Comment: FYI, you are open to XSS attacks.  Escape any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML with `htmlspecialchars()`.  `echo '<form method="post" action="matchmaking.php?search=', htmlspecialchars($search_summoner), '">';`

Comment: fyi, you dont need an `action` attribute if you're sending form back to original page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery you could set the action parameter like this (add an ID "search" to the form)

```
$('input[name="search_summoner"]').on('keyup'function(){
   $('form#search').attr('action','matchmaking.php?search='+$(this).val());
});
```

So, while typing, the action parameter will be extended by every character of the typed search string.

Comment: or if you don´t want to use a ID for your form $('input[name="search_summoner"]').on('keyup'function(){
   var myform = $(this).closest('form'); myform.attr('action','matchmaking.php?search='+$(this).val());
});

Comment: in this case, using this jquery code, your html code must not have a action attribute, as jquery will add this anyway, if not exists. <form method="post">

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['search_summoner']) && $_POST['search_summoner'] != '')
        {
            $search_summoner = $_POST['search_summoner'];
        }
        else
        {
            $search_summoner = "";
        }

        echo $search_summoner;    // This displays your Query
    ?>  
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>>
            <input type="text" name="search_summoner">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, I think you want to do something like this:

```
$search_summoner = $_POST['search_summoner'];
    echo '<form method="post" action="matchmaking.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="search" value="'.$search_summoner.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="search_summoner">';
    echo '<input type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Well yeah, its also completely weird to do this in general, not to mention annoying echoing every single HTML line. If you check the original post he's asking if its possible to do it, not if it its useful.

Comment: Folks copy and paste code all the time from Stack Overflow.  You should encourage some minimal best practices when you write answers.